# determine liklihood function in GPD distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

if $W_i|W_{i - 1} = w_{i - 1}$ have GPD distribution with parameters $\xi$ and $\exp(a+bw_{i-1})$ whose $a$, $b$, and $\xi$ can be estimated by maximising 
$\prod\limits_{i = 2}^n f_{W_i\mid W_{i - 1}}(w_i\mid w_{i - 1}) f_{W_1}(w_1)$. Note that the marginal distribution $W_i$ will not be GPD and that chain need not be stationary. These models for the GPD parameters were obtained by model comparisions on the likelihood ratio statistic. Amongest the possible alternative models we tried different semi-parametric models for $\exp(a+bw_{i-1})$. a possible diagnostic for the marginal distribution may be based on that fact that when the GPD parameter model is correct the residuals

$$R_j = \hat \xi ^{ - 1} \log (1 + \hat \xi w_j \exp (\hat a + \hat b w_{j - 1}))$$

are approximately independent unit exponential variables.
How can we determine this [likelihood function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)?

Comment: I cleaned up some of your MathJax code but I'm not sure what to make of that last bit.  It looks as if it was written either by a software package or a lunatic.

Comment: ok, Now I've attempted to clean up the last part.  I can't be sure that it's what you intended.